# Ignore last space in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to ignore last space in R
Example

```
asd <- "North America "
```

expected output

```
asd 
"North America"
```

Comment: Try this: `gsub(" $", "", asd)`.

Comment: Read about `trimws`